# React Hook "useAxios" is called in function that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I created a custom `useAxios` hook to make api calls.

I am trying to use this in my login component as below.

```
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import './login.scss';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAxios } from '../../api/use-axios';
import ApiConfig from '../../api/api-config';
import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';

const LOGIN_AXIOS_CONFIG = ApiConfig.AUTH.LOGIN;

const Login = () => {
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState('');
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    LOGIN_AXIOS_CONFIG.data = {
      phone,
      password,
    };
    const { response: loginData, error } = useAxios(LOGIN_AXIOS_CONFIG);
    if (error) {
      setLoginError(error);
    } 
    if (loginData) {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: loginData });
        navigate('/');
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="logo">
        <h1>LOGO</h1>
        <h3>LOGO DESCRIPTION</h3>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <input type="number" placeholder="phone" onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} />
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        {loginError && <span>{loginError}</span>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

*use-axios.js*

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAxios = (axiosParams) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(undefined);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async (params) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.request({
        ...params,
        method: params.method || 'GET',
        headers: {
          accept: 'application/json',
          authorization:
            'Bearer my-token',
        },
      });
      console.log(result.data);
      setResponse(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(axiosParams);
  }, [axiosParams]); // execute once only

  return { response, error, loading };
};
```

Is react seeing `use` prefix and giving error?

How can I fix this?

Comment: this line `const { response: loginData, error } = useAxios(LOGIN_AXIOS_CONFIG)` needs to be *outside* the `handleLogin` function. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: So, what should I do in handle login when the form is submit? Also, When it initially renders those will be `''` in that case `useAxios()` will fail? Can you post the final solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a slight change to your custom hook `useAxios` since hooks can be invoked only in the body of the component and not conditionally. I add a param to that hook to handle the auto-fetch. In this case you don't want it to trigger automatically the fetch, but imperatively, so just return the fetcher function from the hook and use it imperatively. It would be better not to couple the hook btw and create two separate hooks, something like `useAxiosOnMount`, `useAxiosOnAction`. For simplicity I'll just edit your `useAxios` hook here:

```
const Login = () => {
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState('');
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const {fetch, loading, response, error} = useAxios(LOGIN_AXIOS_CONFIG, false)

  useEffect(() => {
   if (response) // do something
   if (error) // do something else
  },[response,error])

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch()
  };

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="logo">
        <h1>LOGO</h1>
        <h3>LOGO DESCRIPTION</h3>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <input type="number" placeholder="phone" onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} />
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        {loginError && <span>{loginError}</span>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

use-axios.js

export const useAxios = (axiosParams, isAuto) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(undefined);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async (params) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.request({
        ...params,
        method: params.method || 'GET',
        headers: {
          accept: 'application/json',
          authorization:
            'Bearer my-token',
        },
      });
      console.log(result.data);
      setResponse(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuto)
    fetchData(axiosParams);
  }, [axiosParams, isAuto]); // execute once only

  return { fetch: () => fetchData(axiosParams), response, error, loading };
};
```

Comment: I think it's slightly better.

Comment: The modern fetch libraries like RTK Query, apollo, etc... use a similar distinction among GET calls to be executed on mount, called `queries` that expose a *lazy* alternative that returns a fetcher function to execute the fetch lazily ( as in your example, onclick ), and POST,PUT,PATCH, etc... called `mutations` that are only meant to be executed lazily, so they always expose a fetcher function.

Comment: I noticed one issue with above method. `error` will never bet the current error. It is always the previous api call error. How to fix this?

Comment: is not it going to create a loop. as we are using useEffect on response?

Comment: @JeetDaloneboy You mean using **response** in the effect deps ? So what's the problem with that ? That means the effect will run only on mount and if the axios request is completed with a response or an error.
You would have a loop only if you fetched again inside that effect.

Answer (score 0):

`useAxios`, as you designed it, is a hook. And a hook, should follow some rules, known as [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html),  and here is an overview:

> It should only get called a the to level of a React component or at the top level of a hook, not in a function inside a hook or a component like you did, not inside any other block, like if-else...

An approche for your case may be something like this:

```js
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './login.scss';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAxios } from '../../api/use-axios';
import ApiConfig from '../../api/api-config';
import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';

const LOGIN_AXIOS_CONFIG = ApiConfig.AUTH.LOGIN;

const Login = () => {
  const [loginAxioConfig, setLogicAxiosConfig]=useState(null);
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState('');
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const { response: loginData, error } = useAxios(loginAxioConfig);
  
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLogicAxiosConfig({...LOGIN_AXIOS_CONFIG, data = {
      phone,
      password,
    } });
    
  };
  
  useEffect(()=>{
   if (error) {
      setLoginError(error);
   } 
  },[error]);

   useEffect(()=>{
     if (loginData) {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: loginData });
      navigate('/');
     }
  },[loginData])
  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="logo">
        <h1>LOGO</h1>
        <h3>LOGO DESCRIPTION</h3>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <input type="number" placeholder="phone" onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} />
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        {loginError && <span>{loginError}</span>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAxios = (axiosParams) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(undefined);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async (params) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.request({
        ...params,
        method: params.method || 'GET',
        headers: {
          accept: 'application/json',
          authorization:
            'Bearer my-token',
        },
      });
      console.log(result.data);
      setResponse(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!axiosParams) return;
    fetchData(axiosParams);
  }, [axiosParams]);

  return { response, error, loading };
};
```

Comment: I updated the `handleLogin` please have a look. Why are you setting error state with all those config values, while it should be error coming from response i.e. *useAxios*?

Comment: I'am not setting error. I'm using an state for LOGIN_AXIOS_CONFIG, I trigger a render when there is a change, and then `useAxios` will take over. I just edited my answer. Try it please and tell me if its work.

Comment: So, When it initially renders phone and password will be `''` in that case useAxios() will fail? Will it go in error state until it re-renders?

Comment: Yeah initially it will fail.

Comment: That's weird making a api call twice? Moreover deliberately making it fail? :(

Comment: Yeah I get you, however you can use a trick in `useAxios` to not make this call. I'am gonna add that in my response.

Comment: I add a codition in `useAxios`'s  `useEffect` and giving it null at first value in Login component. This way there wouldn't be this additional api call meant to fail.

Comment: I also realised that I was calling `setLoginError`  while I meant to call `setLogicAxiosConfig` actually in `handleLogin`.

Comment: Why not return from `useAxios` itself than going into useEffect?

Comment: Yeah you could do that, I think.

Comment: Nope, it gives warning. `React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.` :)

Comment: Yeah my bad, you can't actually.